# OpenAPI 3.0 map json with dynamic variable names and values

Tags: java, openapi

I'm trying to map a json in openapi 3.0 components.

The json structure looks like:

```
- X    
    X1
       Xx1
         ….
         ….
       Xx2
       Xx3   
    X2
       Xx21
       xx22
       Xx23  
   X3
     Xx31
     Xx32
     Xx33 
   Y    
    Y1
     YY1
     YY2    
     YY3    
      …    
    Y2  
      …    
    Y3 
    … …
```

This is basically a json tree with at least 4 layers

Given the fact the variable name and values can be dynamic, depending on the language the user is choosing i don't know how can i achieve that in openapi.

Any help is welcomed!

I was trying to achieve that using enums, but there are no ways of creating enums of enums of enums in openapi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.